# Datatable and Highcharter in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to link datatable with highcharter? For example, click on any line of the table, the highcharter will show result in dynamic?

Comment: If you are using DT, have a look at `rows_selected`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, select any row you want and see the chart (highchart) react to selected values:

```
library(highcharter)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
db <- mtcars
ui <- fluidPage(DTOutput("my_dt"),
                highchartOutput("my_hc"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_dt <- renderDT({
    db
  })
  output$my_hc <- renderHighchart({
    db_hc <-
      db[input$my_dt_rows_selected, ] # filter dataset according to select rows in my_dt
    hc <- highchart() %>%
      hc_add_series(name = "mpg", data = db_hc$mpg) %>%
      hc_add_series(name = "wt", data = db_hc$wt)
    hc
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope it helps!